# Can't boot/access Ubuntu LTS 18.04 after erasing Windows

Tags: boot, system-installation

Yesterday I decided to install Ubuntu 18.04 to replace Windows on my other laptop for work, I already had Ubuntu 18.04 on a USB so I just plugged it in, booted the laptop and started it using the USB and then while the laptop restarted I selected Install Ubuntu instead of try without installing.

However, after the installation was complete, I never managed to access Ubuntu instead it kept reloading me to that same screen with 4 options (1: try without installing, 2: install Ubuntu, 3: OEM install, 4:check disk for defects).  I first thought I had an installation problem so I went to install it again but the Ubuntu installer gave me the weird option to: **Install Ubuntu LTS 18.04 alongside Ubuntu LTS 18.04**. So I realized it actually got installed and I just can't access it.

Keep in mind that during my first Install I checked that everything gets erased (no more Windows) and I keep only the Ubuntu OS.

I tried a few things I found online **(changing something in BIOS, changing boot order in BIOS, something in GNU GRUB...)** but I don't know much about how to deal this and I need help accessing Ubuntu. Note that one source told me to simply remove the USB and reboot the laptop but that didn't work instead it gave me that there is nothing bootable on the laptop (?).

How can I access Ubuntu? How do I fix this problem?

[image: Here is a picture of the boot priority order]

[image: Here is a picture of what I get when I remove the USB stick and reboot]

Comment: You need to remove your USB so the computer starts from the hard drive rather than from the USB.

Comment: @vanadium I just posted what happens when I remove the USB

Comment: Rearrange your post: currently you describe the situation that lets us believe you leave the USB in. Inform also whether this is classical (MBR) boot or modern UEFI boot: that can be seen in your bios settings.

Comment: When I keep the USB it keeps giving me the four options mentioned above, when I remove it, it tells me that there is no bootable disk. I did my research on the bios where I should switch from UEFI to Legacy, however my laptop's Bios does not have the ability to switch from UEFI to Legacy (I did not find it in the boot tab in bios).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your laptop is an Acer. In order to disable secure boot follow these steps:

1. Make sure your UEFI is up to date.
2. In UEFI, you must set a supervisor password. Once the supervisor password is set, some new menus are accessible.
3. Enter the "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing" menu. It will allow you to declare the newly installed Ubuntu boot image as trusted on your laptop.
4. Select EMMC >> EFI >> Ubuntu and select the file shimx64.efi. You will be prompted to give it a name of your choice (which will appear in the F12 boot options).
5. Type the name press Enter and then "Yes" should be highlighted.
6. Press enter again. Restart the computer without any boot disk and tap F12 during the boot process.
7. You should now get the boot option menu with the name you chose.
8. You can change the boot order in UEFI now so that it boots directly to the Grub screen.
9. Either disable the supervisor password, or save it in a secure place.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated :)